# How to restrict user to use exe of .net windows for only certain days for trial

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I have a exe of .net windows application. I want to share exe with client for trial so want to restrict uses of only 1 week. I was supposing to use `DateTime` and compare with current date but it don't work if user change the system date back.

Any solution?

Comment: There are also ways around pretty much any restriction you put on the user. You could simply store the date (somewhere) when the user first loads app, and just have the app check for one week past *that* date, that is, you are then taking the *system date* **entirely out of the equation**.

Comment: You're trying to restrict usage of your application based on the state of a system which your malicious attacker completely controls. Impossible, but the strongest approach is to introduce state they cannot control--that is, you need to register the demo application with your own servers and require *them* to okay the application before it works. Still not impenetrable, but less trivial to defeat and may let you get safely by if your target market is small and non-technical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application requires Internet access, you could have it test the current date and time by calling the following web service which returns a time string:

```
http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now
```

for instance, it will return

```
2013-09-23T11:05:08+01:00
```

which is the current time in ISO 8601 format. Notice that the first characters represent the current date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

If your app does not require Internet access, you may still require that every 5 times or so that the user starts up the app, you get to check the current time over the Internet. Many applications today, including on smartphones, require Internet access just to contact a server or to verify a registration key.

Comment: Whats stopping a user from resetting the "application start counter"?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: You could keep that in Isolated Storage or in the Registry, and apply encryption to it. For instance, you could store an XML file that contains a key and a value; the key is derived from the current date and time (as retrieved from the Web service) and can be decrypted easily by the application. The application uses the key to determine when the value was last updated. Of course that timestamp must be before the current timestamp as reported by Windows, or the (key, value) pair is invalid. If it is valid, you can use the key to decrypt the value, which must then be 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Check when the user starts the app and store the count of date in a Hidden File

Sample

```
if (File.Exists("startapp.txt")
{
    using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("startapp.txt"));
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("startapp.txt"); 
        int count = int.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
        sr.Close();
        count++;
        writeFile.WriteLine(count.ToString());
    }
}
else
{
    FileStream fs = File.Create("startapp.txt");
    fs.Close();
    File.SetAttributes(
    "startapp.txt", 
    FileAttributes.Archive | 
    FileAttributes.Hidden | 
    );
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.WriteLine("1");
}
```

Then you can read the file and check if it is `7`.